# Bash login script: where did that [1] error come from?

Tags: bash

I have a fairly complex script I use to log-in:

```
`/Users/tinosino/.profile`
```

Shell scripting language: Bash

I can not change the login script other than request bug fixes if I spot any issues.

Whenever I login these days, if I run this:

```
echo $?
```

immediately, I get:

```
1
```

Something is failing in the script.

**How can I pinpoint the cause of the error?** The exact line returning that error code? Is it possible to "trap" for certain exit codes, switch trapping on and abort the `.profile` script at that point?

I know about running Bash with -x but the output is completely overwhelming: complex script, thousands of lines.

- Can I somehow just have it "stop" and give me control when `1` is returned?
- Can I alternatively do something like `$?` and see the culprit command line like I see the exit code?

Looking at `history` and `$HISTFILE` hasn't helped much. Too complex.

I think that trapping this kind of errors could be even "generally useful" to me in the future. Maybe even to other users as well?

Comment: *other than request bug fixes if I spot any issues* - I would say you have spotted an issue.  It means enough to you to go and ask strangers about it.

Comment: Since you see `$?` equal to 1 on login, it's either the last command in your `.profile`, or something that sets your prompt. Start at the bottom of the `-x` output and work your way up.

Comment: @chepner: Hi. If I run `echo foo` then `$?` is not 1 anymore.. This rules out it being the PS1/PROMPT_COMMAND hypothesis?

Comment: Perhaps. It's possible that something run in PS1/PROMPT_COMMAND may depend on state that changes after you run that first command (in this case, `echo foo`): something to do with shell history, a file whose contents change, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to trap, but seriously, if you consider the output to be too complex and overwhelming, then you are probably not the right person to go chasing it.

OK, let's say you have no choice.  First off, don't throw your arms in the air and say something is too complex.  Someone wrote it, and I'll bet they were no more intelligent than you are - in fact it takes great skill to write code that *does not* appear too complex.  Complex code is easy to write.

Second, how do you know there is an error?  `$?` being 1 is not necessarily an error, it can be set by a condition being false, and that might be expected.

So, there is a way to stop execution on an error.  When you run the script, run it with `bash -e script-name`.  That is generally frowned-upon as bad practice, but you sound desperate!  It will not stop as the result of failure in a conditional statement.

Comment: I dig your style. Inspiring self-confidence in people is always positive (ref: _I'll bet they were no more intelligent than you are_). And generous. I appreciate that. `bash -e` does what I asked: stop the script upon encountering the first error message..

Answer (score 0):

You can also try running the command with strace for debugging. It will show you information on system calls and received signals.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace

Answer (score 0):

Shell profiles are just regular shell scripts that are `source`'d instead of executed.  The difference is explained in the `man`page:

```
source filename [arguments]
  Read  and  execute commands from filename in the current shell environment and return the exit status of the last command executed from filename.
```

So, just like a running a shell script from the command line, the exit code of a sourced profile is that of the *last* command executed in the profile.  So, if you're sure that `/Users/tinosino/.profile` is the very last profile sourced before you get your command prompt, then the exit code of 1 is coming from the very last command executed in that file.  So all you need to look for are the points at which there is an `exit` called in that file and the very last command in that file.